# How to get last day of previous month in UNIX (HPUX)

Tags: ksh, date

I am creating a script that collects information from the previous month used for reporting:

So far I have the below variables:

```
#I used an array to get the previous month. 
set -A months Dec Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov
x=`date +%m`  
y=`expr $x - 1`
year=`date +%Y`
month=`perl -MPOSIX=strftime -le '@t = localtime; $t[3] = 1; $t[4]--;print strftime("%m", @t)'`
month_abv=`echo ${months[$y]}`
```

Variable output:

```
year=2017
month=04
month_abv=Apr
```

All I need now is the last day of the previous month.

Comment: Both Linux and HP-UX at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I went about getting the last day of the previous month is:

```
cal $month $year | awk 'NF {DAYS = $NF}; END {print DAYS}'
```

Using the varaible placeholders I am able to get the previous months calander and printing the last day of the month:

```
cal 04 2017 | awk 'NF {DAYS = $NF}; END {print DAYS}'
```

Output:

```
30
```

If there is an easier way or shorter way please, I am open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

You could calculate one day before the first day of this month, using GNU `date`:

```
date -d "$(date +"%Y-%m-01") - 1 day" +"%F"
```

or using `dateutils`'s `dateadd`:

```
dateadd "$(date +"%Y-%m-01")" "-1d"
```

or a bit tricky `dateutils` usage. Round to the last 31th month day. (Documented behavior which works even for months with less than 31 days.)

```
$ dateround --next today -31d
2017-04-30
$ dateround --next "2016-03-10" -31d
2016-02-29
```

Comment: These are often not available on HP-UX.

Comment: The reason why I did not use date -d, because it does not work in HPUX unfortunately

Comment: @ChristopherKarsten I know. My solution is about either installing "dateutils" or "GNU date". There is no single operating systems on the planet where `dateutils` is installed by default. But nevertheless there are people who use it ... ;)

Comment: @rudimeier, have anyone installed `dateutils` on HP-UX? I don't seem to find any matches on Google.

Comment: @saulius2 It should be possible to build dateutils from the the released source tarballs: https://bitbucket.org/hroptatyr/dateutils/downloads/ , if something does not work, the author will be happy about a bug-report/question: https://github.com/hroptatyr/dateutils/issues

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
eval "$(
  LC_ALL=C perl -MPOSIX -le '
    @t = localtime;
    $t[3]=0; # set day to 0 (day before the first)
    print strftime q(year=%Y month=%m day=%d month_abv="%b"), @t'
)"
```

`perl` constructs some shell code (like `year=2017 month=04 day=30 month_abv="Apr"`) which we then `eval`uate into the current shell (assuming a POSIX shell).

`LC_ALL=C` is to force the month_abv to be in English regardless of the locale. Remove it if you'd rather it be in the user's locale.

That `day=0` trick works with the `strftime()` of GNU, FreeBSD and Solaris, but I don't know how portable it is outside of that.

To get the *first* day, of the previous month, replace `$t[3]=0` with `$t[3]=1; $t[4]--` which for me works even if run in January but again, I'm not sure how portable it is.

Comment: I know this nice `strftime`, `mktime` and `struct tm` behavior. But I always wondered whether this is documented somewhere in perl or POSIX documentation. I could only find it for glibc (man mktime).

Comment: @rudimeier, I can't say the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/functions/mktime.html) is very clear on that. _values[...] shall not be restricted to the ranges described in <time.h>_, but that's not saying how the time should be calculated if you use 1234 as the day of the month number or a negative month.

Comment: Interesting, in POSIX 2003 was "components *are* not restricted" instead of *shall*. Sounds somehow weaker now.

Answer (score 2):

The below seems to work OK for me on ksh88 (thanks to Stéphane Chazelas for some assistance with this)

```
#! /bin/ksh
eval "$(date +'y=%Y m=%m')"
echo "Current month = $m"
echo "Current year = $y"

#get previous month (and year of previous month)
if [[ $((m-1)) -gt 0 ]]
then
    p_m=$((m-1))
    p_m_y=$((y))
else
    p_m=12
    p_m_y=$((y-1))
fi
echo "p_m = $p_m"
echo "p_m_y = $p_m_y"

#get first/last day of previous month
p_m_from=01.${p_m}.${p_m_y}
p_m_to=$(cal $p_m $p_m_Y | grep -v ^$ | tail -1 | sed 's/^.* \([0-9]*\)$/\1/').${p_m}.${p_m_y}
echo "Previous month runs from $p_m_from to $p_m_to"
```

Comment: This is pretty decent

Answer (score 0):

To find previous month follow this:

```
date -d "-1 months" +%Y/%-m/%-d
```

This will give you: `2018/2/22` while it is `2018/3/22`.

```
date -d "-1 days" +%Y/%-m/%-d
```

Will give you: `2018/3/21`

You can add or subtract as many months or days you like. If you subtract enough months it will go to last year.